# I need to make a backup of a SSD 240 GB

Tags: backup

i need a help !!

what do you suggest for my question:

I need to make a backup of a SSD 240 GB (that was with Win10). What tool do you recommend me to do on Linux (Ubuntu) in the cloud?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use clonezilla live, check it out:
https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php

Comment: thank you  !!!!!!!!!!!